# JavaScript / HTML: Disable Block of Code Only in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, opera

I want to tell Opera to ignore a block of JavaScript code, but I want all other browsers to recognize that code, something like this:

```
if NOT Opera:

<script type="text/javascript">

// Code

</script>
```

Or maybe rather:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 if NOT Opera:

// Code

</script>
```

Is there a solution? I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") < 0 ) {
    // Code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much all you need is to take a look at the [`window.navigator.userAgent` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent). Within it you'll find a string containing information about the browser you are using. I have no access to a version of safari so I can't really test this out for you -

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.match('/safari/i')){
  // user is using safari
}
```

References -

- [`window.navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent)
- [`string.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

---

Keep in mind that this is not the best way to do browser detection and will not prevent people from using your site with safari - your JavaScript is viewable and editable by all so if you are thinking of this as a security feature you might want to reconsider it.

I would suggest detecting the users browser on the server side (if you are using PHP then you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`) and then have the server return different JavaScript files according to the users browser.

Comment: Are you sure `navigator.appName` is the one you wanted to put here? `navigator.appName` returns `"Netscape"` for every browser except IE, and all Webkit based browsers include `"Safari"` in `navigator.appVersion`.

Comment: @der - looks like you are correct.. Thanks for that feedback! I've made some edits to reflect that...

Comment: @Lix - `userAgent` looks better.